# Batch file - construct full path dynamically

Tags: batch-file

I have the following folder structure:

```
FolderX
    FolderY1
        FolderZ
    FolderY2
        FolderZ
    FolderY3
        FolderZ
    ...
```

I need to copy all files from `FolderX\FolderY<i>\FolderZ` into `Target`, where `FolderY<i>` is the most recent folder in `FolderX`.

So in the example above, I would simply do:

```
xcopy FolderX\FolderY3\FolderZ Target
```

But I need to apply this on the general case.

There are two ways by which `FolderY<i>` can be identified:

1. The folder with the most recent time-stamp
2. The folder with the last name by alphabetic order

How can I obtain the full path, using either one of these identification methods?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to get the name of latest sub-directory in your FolderX directory and set variable to it, that can then be used later in script:

```
for /F %%i in ('dir /B /OD /AD FolderX') do set latest_file=%%i
```

(Note: if on comand line use %i, instead of %%i)

Comment: Thanks. And how do I use `latest_file` after that? Is `FolderX\%latest_file%\FolderZ` correct?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to do it by alphabetic order as well? Is it `ON` instead of `OD`?